# OPENCV.js Cannot get Emscripten path

Tags: linux, opencv

I am trying to setup OPENCV.js on linux.But I have infuriating problems on Empscripten path.
I am following this documentation:https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d4/da1/tutorial_js_setup.html

1-)I download empscripten and  execute following code.

```
./emsdk update
./emsdk install latest
./emsdk activate latest
```

2-)Set the environment path

```
source ./emsdk_env.sh
```

3-)Clone opencv with git

```
git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git
```

4-)To build this directory (/root/Downloads/opencvjspackage)

```
 python ./platforms/js/build_js.py /root/Downloads/opencvjspackage
```

I get this output on part 4

```
root@kali:~/Downloads/opencvjs/opencv# python ./platforms/js/build_js.py /root/Downloads/opencvjspackage
Args: Namespace(build_dir='/root/Downloads/opencvjspackage', build_doc=False, build_test=False, build_wasm=False, clean_build_dir=False, config_only=False, emscripten_dir=None, enable_exception=False, opencv_dir='/root/Downloads/opencvjs/opencv', skip_config=False)
Cannot get Emscripten path, please specify it either by EMSCRIPTEN environment variable or --emscripten_dir option.
```

I try this

```
python ./platforms/js/build_js.py /root/Downloads/opencvjspackage --emscripten_dir=/root/Downloads/emsdk-portable/emscripten/1.37.33
```

And get this output:

```
usage: build_js.py [-h] [--opencv_dir OPENCV_DIR]
                   [--emscripten_dir EMSCRIPTEN_DIR] [--build_wasm]
                   [--build_test] [--build_doc] [--clean_build_dir]
                   [--skip_config] [--config_only] [--enable_exception]
                   build_dir
build_js.py: error: too few arguments
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be no `=` between `--emscripten_dir` and the Empscripten path. Also the output folder should be the last argument.
Try like this:

```
python ./platforms/js/build_js.py --emscripten_dir /root/Downloads/emsdk-portable/emscripten/1.37.33 /root/Downloads/opencvjspackage
```

Tip: make sure `/root/Downloads/opencvjspackage` exists and is where you want `opencv.js` to be built into. Also make sure `cmake` is installed.